# ogr2ogr batch process tries to open zip files instead of .gdb

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr, batch

I am using a semi-automatic analysis using a lot of datasets. To do so, I run a .bat file in OSGeo4W Shell that takes all the unpacked files in a folder and packages them in one .gpkg file for further processing. It shouldn't try to open .zip/.rar files but only their unpacked contents which lie in the same folder. Some datasets are only available as .gml or .shp however. I would like the batch process to ignore all .zip and .rar files as it just rejects files with the same name (tries the zip and then ignores the gdb). Any ideas how I could include .gdb/.shp/.gml files and exclude .shp/.rar files? Here's a snippet from the .bat file:

```
C:\GIS Filer\DOK-Analyse data>ogr2ogr -nln Skogsressurskart -overwrite -f GPKG QGIS-analyse/inndata.gpkg -t_srs EPSG:25832 *_SR16_* SkogressursFlate
ERROR 1: Couldn't fetch requested layer '5036_25833_SR16_GDB.zip'!

C:\GIS Filer\DOK-Analyse data>ogr2ogr -nln Reindrift -append -f GPKG QGIS-analyse/inndata.gpkg -t_srs EPSG:25832 *_reindrift-ekspropriasjonsomrade_*.g* reindrift_ekspropriasjonsomrade_flate
```

As you can see, the `*_reindrift-ekspropriasjonsomrade_*.g*` includes files with a .g* ending, but not the .shp files.

Edit: Here is a *very* short form of the batch file:

```
del QGIS-analyse\inndata.gpkg
ogr2ogr -nln Teig -overwrite -f GPKG QGIS-analyse/inndata.gpkg -t_srs EPSG:25832 *Teig_* teig
```

It deletes the old file and creates a new *inndata.gpkg* which it then adds files from the same folder to. In the example above it adds the file that has "Teig_" in the name and in this case also extracts the layer "teig". Like I said, this works in some cases, but not all. Typos are not to blame here and also the file type is the same.

Comment: Ogr2ogr does not support wildcards in input/output names. Write a Windows batch file with FOR https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/for.

Comment: Well, as you can see it works for the second file. In fact, using the wildcard fixed a problem there, just not in its entirety. Or am I missing something? I am quite new to batch processing.

Comment: Please show your whole batch file or at least a simplified version that is still operable. But the question is missing a GIS component so maybe it belongs to some other forum.

Comment: Hi, I added a short version of the batch file. I think this is GIS relevant as the command only runs in OSGeo4W Shell and extracts GIS layers to add them to geopackage.

Comment: To be sure, is your final aim to add the contents of layer "teig" from several datasources which match the name pattern `*Teig_*` and which are either .shp, .gml, or .gdb, into one geopackage layer named "Teig"?

Answer (score 1):

Ogr2ogr supports only one source datasource and one target datasource. The synopsis is documented in  https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html

```
ogr2ogr [--help-general] [-skipfailures] [-append] [-update]
        [-select field_list] [-where restricted_where|@filename]
        [-progress] [-sql <sql statement>|@filename] [-dialect dialect]
        [-preserve_fid] [-fid FID] [-limit nb_features]
        [-spat xmin ymin xmax ymax] [-spat_srs srs_def] [-geomfield field]
        [-a_srs srs_def] [-t_srs srs_def] [-s_srs srs_def] [-ct string]
        [-f format_name] [-overwrite] [[-dsco NAME=VALUE] ...]
        dst_datasource_name src_datasource_name
        [-lco NAME=VALUE] [-nln name]
        [-nlt type|PROMOTE_TO_MULTI|CONVERT_TO_LINEAR|CONVERT_TO_CURVE]
        [-dim XY|XYZ|XYM|XYZM|2|3|layer_dim] [layer [layer ...]]
```

Line **dst_datasource_name src_datasource_name** means that those two arguments are compulsory, they must appear in that order, and they can appear only one time in a command..

If you want to run the same ogr2gr command for several datasources you must run a separate ogr2ogr command for each. A FOR loop can be utilized for that purpose. A simple example that combines all shapefiles into one GeoPackage layer:

```
for /f %i in ('dir /b p*.shp') DO ogr2ogr -f gpkg -update -append combined.gpkg %i -nln combined_layer
```

This example can be edited for your exact use case but there are some challenges. For example you cannot overwrite the geopackage in the loop or otherwise just the contents of the last source data layer would remain. The geometry type and attribute schema of all input layers must also be similar.

Comment: Sorry to answer so late. That is a good explanation, thank you! I think I can create a workaround with that information.